# Blocking UI on document ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

I'm working on a web application which needs to be compatible with Internet Explorer 8 (you know, compatible with the **HELL**). The thing is that I´m uploading a file which later is processed by a PHP code and refresh the page. When I have a processed file I used that file to insert data into a table, so I need a processbar and block UI while I insert this data (I need to call another PHP process for each row)

The problem is the next one, I want to block that UI, I have the logic and all compatibility problems solved; but after 5 days of work, I can´t block UI. This is a minimum code (which encapsulate all we need) in order to simplify the idea:

```
    $(document).ready({
    (...)
        $("#title").html('some text');
        $("#bar").html('');
        $.blockUI({message: $('#window'),css:{width:'303px'}});
        go = true;
        while (go){
            $.ajax({<ASYNC FALSE AJAX CALL});
            if (!file.lines) go = false;
            <update progress>
        }

        $.unblockUI();
    (...)
    });
```

Obviously, the *$.blockUI* should block main thread (until I unblocks) and show a personalized window, which have the next code is:

```
<div id="window" style="display: none; cursor: default">
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="titulos">some text</div>
        <div id="cerrar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <img src="an icon"
            alt="enviando" border="0" width="33" height="33" id="enviar">
        <p class="titulo" id='title'></p>
        <p class="texto" id='bar'></p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is that I´m executing that block on a thread which is not main thread, and i cant really blocks UI; but I need that block because I have to force the user to wait until I process all of the information.

Thank guys, I hope you could help me with this.

Comment: Try removing `async: false`. It's extremely bad practice to use it, and it means that your UI won't be updated, which will interfere with the `blockUI` plugin you're using.

Comment: Any error you are getting. or do you have fiddle ?

Comment: I cant remove the `async: false`, I know it's a bad practice but I need it on this piece of code @RoryMcCrossan . I dont having any error, the developer console says the typical warnig about the `async: false`.

Comment: I'm 99% sure there's another way to do what you require without `async: false`, and I'm also pretty sure that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've just try the `async: true` deleting the `while` condition (if I left that while It blocks the browser) and still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mostly because of synchronous, but if you make it async you need make the changes in your code. Remove while-loop and invoke a function, that will make an async call and on successful completion invoke the same function recursively. Once your terminal condition is met, unblock the UI as below:

```
 $.blockUI({message: $('#window'),css:{width:'303px'}});
 //  based on the above code I assume you will get file as a response.
 process();

 function process(file){
     if (file && !file.lines){
         $.unblockUI();
     }

     $.ajax({<ASYNC TRUE AJAX CALL})
      .done(function(file){                   
               <update progress>
               process(file);
          });
 }
```

Comment: Well, thank you so much. That was the perfect idea. I didn't think about recursive functions. So now it's working correctly. Thanks!!!!